# Increment an integer in a Simple.Data Update query

Tags: sql, simple.data

Is it possible to increment an integer in an Update query using Simple.Data?

My database is SQL Server, but I know Simple.Data is designed to be database agnostic so perhaps this query is not available in other providers.

The SQl query I am trying to generate would look like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyInt = MyInt + 1 WHERE Id = 123
```

Currently I have to do a SELECT and an UPDATE in Simple.Data to achieve the same thing:

```
var result = db.MyTable.Find(db.MyTable.Id == 123);
result.MyInt++;
db.MyTable.UpdateById(Id: result.Id, MyInt: result.MyInt );
```

I am wondering if there is a way to replicate the single SQL statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
db.MyTable.UpdateById(Id: 123, MyInt: db.MyTable.MyInt + 1);
```

Works on SQL Server, should work in all the SQL-based providers.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Should this work with InMemoryAdapter too?  It seems to reset the value of MyInt to 0.

Comment: It doesn't work with InMemoryAdapter right now. That feature is up for a total rewrite in 2.0 and should support almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this does not work if the int is nullable and the current value is null.  Nothing happens.  But if I set the value to 0 then it works.  So my int col now has a default of 0.